# `render_block` not rendering anything in sekizai

Tags: django, django-cms, django-sekizai

I have two files, `base.html` and `homepage.html`.  Homepage extends base, and adds to block `extra`.  Base should render block `extra` in a span within the body, but doesn't.

base.html:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span style="color: red;">{% render_block "extra" %}</span>
        {% block 'content' %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

homepage.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load sekizai_tags %}

{% block 'content' %}
    <p>that's some sweet content ya got there lad</p>
    {% addtoblock "extra" %}wow{% endaddtoblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the output:

[image: Just the <p>, the <span> is empty.]

What really simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I was missing a context preprocessor from my templates.

```
'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
```